# JQuery .load into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Before I switched a lot of my pages to load straight into the DOM I used to use e.g.

```
<div class="msgs_holder" id="wall_comments"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#wall_comments').load('/pages/includes/list_wall.php', { wl_id:"<?=$wl_id?>" });
</script>
```

Which works great, now I'm trying the following but nothing is being loaded, is this the correct way to go? Have searched but no success yet (I used 1188 as a test id)

```
html += '<li><div class="msgs_holder" id="wall_comments"></div></li>';
$('#wall_comments').load('/pages/includes/list_wall.php', { wl_id:1188 });
html += 'blah blah etc etc ';
```

All html loading is fine by the way, there's html before and after where I want to load this section and that's all good.

Comment: It won't work until you pass your `html` variable to some `innerHTML` property (or `html()` method in jQuery).

Comment: @VisioN - thanks, updated question, all html is fine its just this that won't load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to load data into html inside variable, try this:

```
$(html).find('#wall_comments').load('/pages/includes/list_wall.php', { wl_id:1188 });
```